# Trapped in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, login

I've downloaded Xubuntu with a

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

or something along those lines. I started up and had the usual login and checked to login into Xubuntu in the drop down menu. Now, I am trapped in Xubuntu using the Xubuntu log in screen and can't select to run other versions. Fairly new to linux thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: it says ubuntu-desktop is already at the latest version

Comment: Sorry. Do `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`. Read [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html) for more.

Comment: okay it said i didn't have gdm so i ran "sudo apt-get install gdm" and it came up with a configure menu. Should i select gdm or lightdm and is that the right program i need

Comment: The desktop manager is what allows you to pick the environment you want when you login. You can pick either. You merely need to configure it to login to the desktop you want.

Comment: okay i did the command, should i try rebooting and see if the menu comes up

Comment: You can just logout from the desktop. **This isn't *Windows***. You can also do a `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart`

Comment: i did it and the launcher thing was really glitchy like my screen had flashing and stuff. I typed my password and hit enter and thankfully it went, should i remove the gdm and redo it or what do you suggest

Comment: You could retry `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`. It's really up to you. I'm almost certainly not running the same hardware as you (and I personally use MATE).